# how to share data between two controllers without using service and rootscope?

Tags: angularjs

i have faced this question in an interview, i know how to share data between two controllers using service and also using root scope. Is there any way to do with in angular to pass data between two controllers without using service and root scope>

Any suggestions please.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJs uses the Observer pattern which consists on sending and reading events.

There are many times when one part of the application changes, other parts needs to be updated. In AngularJS, if the $scope object updates, an event can be triggered to notify another component. The observer pattern incorporates just that - if an object is modified it broadcasts to dependent objects that a change has occurred.

In short:

`$scope.$emit()` OR `$scope.$broadcast()` depending on your position and what is your 'reader'

Then

`$scope.$on()`

Answer (score 1):

The best practice states using a service, you could also use `$rootScope` by assigning object literal `$rootScope.sharedVar`. There's also a `$broadcast` method, which is an observer pattern, works like pub/sub.

The **least recommended** way would be leveraging your `$parent` scope and drilling down your element (depending where it's located in the DOM tree)